# Splash with 9 patch ruins next activity

Tags: android

I have a splash screen with my company's logo in the center of it with a little progress bar under it.
I launch the splash as the first activity, and before that happens I display an image of the splash (without the progress bar, just the logo) using the app's theme background.

I placed a 9 patch image of the in the app's theme android:windowBackground, and when the extension of that file is .9.png - the splash activity is displayed on the top left corner of the screen in a smaller size.
Changing the extension to .png makes the splash display correctly over the whole screen, but of course my first image is stretch horribly ,because it's much smaller than the screen.

Exmaple:
This is the logo

[image: logo]

The picture below is how the app looks when the splash has been loaded and I am using the .9.png extension

[image: .9.png]

The picture below is how the app looks when the splash has been loaded and I am using the .png extension

[image: .png]

The pic above is how I want the splash to look, but without the .9.png extension the app looks like this (picture below) before the splash loads

[image: oh no]

Anybody experienced this issue? Couldn't find it online.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you please post some screen-captures of the issue?

Comment: Edited with example pics

Comment: Maybe I'm just confused in how you're asking, but you say the picture doesn't look right when you don't use the 9 patch version of the logo, so why not just use the 9 patch version?

Comment: I guess writing 'the last pic' was misleading.
What I meant to say is that the 9 patch version displays correctly for the initial splash, but causes the weird bug you see in the second picture for the actual splash.

The not 9 patch version doesn't cause this bug, but stretches bad as you can see in the last pic.

Note: both versions are the same file with a different extension.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue. Instead of changing the app's theme's windowBackground to my 9patch image, I added a new theme with the 9patch background and attached it to my first activity.

So the basic rule is, don't put a 9patch image in the app's theme background. Place it in the first activity's theme instead.

Source for this solution: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/149184/9-patch-splash-screen-initial-window-does-not-fill-screen